# What is _Complex?

Tags: objective-c, c

Reading Objective-C [type encodings documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-encoding.html) (GCC's and Apple's pages somewhat complement each other), I stumbled upon the `_Complex` keyword. I've never heard about it, and when I tried to look it up, I found tons of results talking about erroneous uses of it, but never what it really did.

What is `_Complex`, and how does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A complex number type which looks like it uses half the bit-width for the real part and half for the imaginary part:

> `_Complex double x;` declares `x` as a variable whose real part and imaginary
>   part are both of type `double`.
>   `_Complex short int y;` declares `y` to
>   have real and imaginary parts of type
>   `short int`; this is not likely to be
>   useful, but it shows that the set of
>   complex types is complete.

Posts about "EXC_BAD_ACCESS _Complex double return"

- http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=92768
- http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/Complex.html

Comment: +1, but "half the bit width" is misleading. An `_Complex double` is really a pair of doubles.

Answer (score 1):

[Complex numbers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number)